# Loading a series of JSON objects in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have downloaded a sample dataset from [here](https://labs.semanticscholar.org/corpus/) that is a series of JSON objects.

```
{...}
{...}
```

I need to load them to a pandas dataframe. I have tried below code

```
import pandas as pd
import json

filename = "sample-S2-records"

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(map(json.loads, "sample-S2-records"))
```

But there seems to be parsing error

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Rather than `from_records`, have you tried using the built-in [`pd.from_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) function? It may handle the formatting more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `pandas.read_json` method:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_json('/path/to/file.json', lines=True) 
print data
```

I have tested it with this file, it works fine

Answer (score 2):

The function needs a list of JSON objects. For example,
data = [ json_obj_1,json_obj_2,....]

The file does not contain the syntax for list and just has series of JSON objects. Following would solve the issue:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Load content to a variable
with open('../sample-S2-records/sample-S2-records', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read().strip()

# Split content by new line
content = content.split('\n')

# Read each line which has a json obj and store json obj in a list
json_list = []
for each_line in content:
    json_list.append(json.loads(each_line))

# Load the json list in form of a string
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(json_list))
```